# While loop producing weird div behavior

Tags: php, html, css, while-loop

I have the following code running in my site. It is done to show items 2 by 2, with a line break every time an even number is gotten.

This is all within a DIV:

```
while($info = $items->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
{
echo "<div name='item' id='".$info['color_base1']."' class='itemBox'>
<div class='showItem'><a href='items_descr.php?itemId=".$info[id_item]."'>
<img class='itemImage' alt='' src='images/$info[imageMid].jpg'></img></div></div><br />";
echo "<div class='indexItemText'><font class='similarItemsText'>
<a href='items_descr.php?itemId=".$info[id_item]."'>".$info[name]."</a>
<font class='price'> - $".$info[price]."</div>";
$row_count++;
if ($row_count % 2 == 0) 
    {
echo "<br />"; // close the row if we're on an even record
    }

}
```

The problem is that my resulting CSS is doing something weird. It creates divs for the 1st 2 items and then it creates  tags for the following items, to the point that these come out of the container div where they should be loaded...

Any idea of why this could be happening?

Comment: Please post a sample of the output HTML this produces.  I see all sorts of unclosed tags -- the `<a>`, the deprecated `<font>`...

Comment: Yep, this is poorly conceived HTML. Clean it up with closing tags, replace font with span and try again; it may just work for you then.

Comment: Indent your code properly. Don't use 'echo' to output the HTML. Close PHP tag after 'while' loop. Then you will get clear picture, what is happening with your HTML tags. So many tags are not closed. Never write code messed like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this :-

```
$html = '';
while($info = $items->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
{
    $html.= "<div name='item' id='".$info['color_base1']."' class='itemBox'>
     <div class='showItem'><a href='items_descr.php?itemId=".$info['id_item']."'>
     <img class='itemImage' alt='' src='images/".$info['imageMid'].".jpg' /></div> </div><br />";

    $html.= "<div class='indexItemText'><font class='similarItemsText'>
       <a href='items_descr.php?itemId=".$info['id_item']."'>".$info['name']."</a></font>
       <font class='price'> -$".$info['price']." </font></div>";  

   $row_count++;
   if ($row_count % 2 == 0) 
    {
      $html.= "<br />"; // close the row if we're on an even record
    }
}
 echo $html;
```